# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE - Audio recorder API Error

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

My recording application is giving me the following error:

> blob:https://theharnishes.com/f86f14a7-53cf-4d21-a137-deb145c95b73:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE

You can see three buttons. PLAY, RECORD, and STOP RECORDING. From its context, we should know what button does what. When I clicked the RECORD button, nothing is displayed in the console. When I clicked the STOPPING RECORDING, first, the console logs my array of audio chunk and then the error message. Finally when I clicked the PLAY button, another strange error appeared:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

This error I understand. Because I have requested the video device rather than the audio device. I later changed `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true})` to `{audio:true}`.
I went back to my webpage and the last error didn't go away.  I want the application to play the recorded audio when the PLAY button is clicked.

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/e9bmwsh1/) (be sure to allow the use of your microphone). <sub>It is outsourced, because Stack Snippets don't allow the use of `getUserMedia`.</sub>

```js
var recordedChunck = [];
var audio_play;
var audioRecorder;

function record() {
  document.getElementById("record_message").innerHTML = "Recording...";
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(data);
      audioRecorder.start();
      audioRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(event) {
        recordedChunck.push(event.data);
        console.log(recordedChunck);
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

function Stop() {
  audioRecorder.stop();
  var blob = new Blob(recordedChunck);
  var audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio_play = new Audio(audioUrl);
}

function play() {
  audio_play.play();
}
```

```html
<p id="record_message">
</p>
<button onclick="record()" style="color:blue; font-size:16px;">
RECORD
</button>
<button onclick="Stop()" style="color:blue; font-size: 16px;">
STOP RECORDING
</button>
<button onclick="play()">
PLAY
</button>
```

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413395).

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "For some reason the error displayed on Stack Overflow is different than mine." Did then someone else edited your post ?

Comment: @Eve I think Toby means that when testing locally they get some error message, but when using the embedded "run code snippet" feature on Stack Overflow, the same code produces a different error. Perhaps Toby can clarify if I have misinterpreted.

Comment: @kaya3, yes, you're correct. When I tested on my own server it gives me this Failed to load resource: net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE  error. However, when tested on Stack Overflow's server, it prints out bunch of JSON objects.

Comment: @Toby I would add not an answer but just a suggestion here, to try to first debug in the simplest mode your code (like an example putting `console.log(typeof audio_play)` and watching all that happens in your functions on each stage, especially with the data types that your code uses. Second one, could you explain why adding an event listener after running the start() and not before it ? Third one - later edit, let's not forget that in html5, the elements intended to play content / streams / are audio and video, NOT the paragraph as you put in your code. Those allow for various source formats.

Comment: @Eve, the reason I've added the dataavailable event listener after the start method of the recording API is to catch any data that might be available to me. The dataavailable event fires when there's data available. Then I'll push bits of data to an array.

Comment: Tried to edit (delete) the wrong part about mentioning the paragraph there, but couldn't do that unless the comment creation was under 5 minutes

Comment: @Toby, My understanding was that you might first prepare the launch of collecting data (by enabling that event listener earlier) in order to be used by that start() process execution. As a comparation, you cannot put a driver on a seat after the car is already moving on the road.

Comment: @Eve, Well, I don't think that would work. For one, even the dataavailable event listener is set before the calling of the start() method, it will not collect anything until the audio starts to record.

Comment: When running `let data = undefined; console.dir(new MediaRecorder(data))` it gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'MediaRecorder': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'`. Moreover, trying to check the possible stream sources that you might use, with `console.dir(navigator.mediaDevices)` you can see its prototype has a method `enumerateDevices`. Not just that but probably could check if a data stream is really collected in the process, e.g `let data = undefined;
console.dir(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(data)) // false` so you might run the stream with all possible checks

Comment: @Eve, the reason you got the error is because you've set the data variable to undefined. For this reason, new MediaRecorder(data) reads as new MediaRecorder(undefined) which is not a media stream. My code, on the other hand, works because the Promise resolves to a media stream which I can pass to the MediaRecorder Object as an argument.

Comment: I did put on purpose `undefined` there just to prove my point that we might check carefully everything (to be able to run the code and show what could be checked and how about streams). I want to provide an answer though I still need to document everything and probably reproduce your errors too. I usually rewrite from scratch a code when it gives big errors so first try to understand what goes wrong with the working environment, too. As such, I wonder if you ran the code from a server or from a desktop computer, where the available memory to process and save a stream probably isn't the same.

Comment: @Eve, Yeah, it's from a server.

Comment: To reiterate what I did say in the linked answer, at the time you call `recorder.stop()`, the `dataavailable` event hasn't fired yet, so `recordedChunck`(sic) is most likely empty, as is the Blob you generate and that's why the media-decoder screams that the provided media can't be read (because it's empty).  Also, don't forget to stop the tracks of your MediaStream when you're done recording it: `audioRecorder.onstop = e => { data.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop()); const blob = new Blob(recordedChunck); const audioURL =...`

Comment: @Eve, all of your smart suggestions did not work for me.